# Let x,y,z such a positive integers; prove the following inequality

Tags: inequality

Let x,y,z such a positive integers we can also prove it for real numbers with $x>y$
Prove that:
$$\frac{(x+y+z)^3\sqrt{xy+y^2}}{(\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x-y})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})}\geq \frac{27(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})xyz}{\sqrt{x-y}}$$
I tried to use AM GM

Comment: Presumably $x>y$ or otherwise you are going to have a problem with $\sqrt{x-y}$?

Comment: @user315918: you could maybe also accept these suitable answers : [(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662874), [(2)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666082),  [(3)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670382),  [(4)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672445),  [(5)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675664),  [(6)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683592),  [(7)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684648),  [(8)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687677). Many thanks :-) !

Comment: And mabye these ones : [(9)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688508),  [(10)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688541),  [(11)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688739),  [(12)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731252), [(13)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739397), [(14)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789562). This would be great!

Answer (score 1):

we have $$(x+y+z)^3\geq 27xyz$$ by $$AM-GM$$ by multiplying the given inequality by $$\frac{\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x+y}}{\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x-y}}>0$$ we have to prove that $$\frac{27xyz\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x+y}}{\sqrt{x-y}-\sqrt{x-y}}\geq 27xyz\sqrt{x-y}$$ but this is true since
$$\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x+y}+x-y\geq \sqrt{x+y}\sqrt{x-y}$$ this is true since after squaring we get
$$y(x+y)+(x-y)(2\sqrt{y}\sqrt{x+y}-2y)\geq 0$$ since
$$2\sqrt {y}\sqrt{x+y}\geq 2y$$ this is true since $$x>0$$

Comment: I may be nitpicking, but there are some words you typed wrong. Such as poove $\rightarrow$ prove, and t5rue $\rightarrow true. Otherwise, your answer is nice.