# Find $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{sin{\pi \cdot \sqrt{x+1}}}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi \cdot \sqrt{x+1})}}{x}$$

I don't how to use L'Hopital so I tried to take $X=\sqrt{x+1}$ so when $x \to 0$ we have $X \to 1$.

But I can't find the real form.

Comment: You don't "know" or you " can't" use l'Hospital?

Comment: Let $f(x)=\sin(\pi \sqrt{x+1})$. Then $f(0)=0$, so you're looking for $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$. But that's just the definition of the derivative at $x=0$...

Comment: @Joanpemo i don't know l'hopital rule

Comment: @Semiclassical i didn't study the derivative

Comment: Let us start in the other direction then: what do you know?

Comment: @user315918 If you don't know about the derivative, you should't be trying to take limits like this. Study basic differentiation first, you'll get much more out of that.

Comment: @Semiclassical I think you should post your elegant solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\;y:=\sqrt{x+1}\;$ , so $\;x\to 0\implies y\to 1\;$ :

$$\lim_{y\to1}\frac{\sin\pi y}{y^2-1}=\lim_{y\to1}\frac{\sin(\pi(y-1)+\pi)}{(y-1)(y+1)}=$$

$$=\lim_{y\to1}\frac{-\sin(\pi(y-1))}{\pi(y-1)}\cdot\frac\pi{y+1}=(-1)\cdot\frac\pi2=-\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the stated question, but 
[L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) really would make life easier here.

In this case, $$f(x) = \sin(\pi \sqrt{x+1}), \space g(x) = x$$
so
$$\frac{d f(x)}{d x} = f'(x) = \cos(\pi \sqrt{x + 1})\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{x+1}}$$
using the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for $\frac{d}{d x} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$, plus $\frac{d}{d x}\sin(x) = \cos(x)$, and $\frac{d}{d x}\sqrt{x+1} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}$. Finally,$$\frac{d g(x)}{d x} = g'(x) = 1$$
Since both $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ exist and $g'(0) \ne 0$, we only need to apply L'Hôpital's rule once:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \sqrt{x+1})}{x} =
  \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\pi \cos(\pi \sqrt{x+1})}{2 \sqrt{x + 1}}$$
which can be directly evaluated at $x=0$:
$$ = \frac{ \pi \cos(\pi) }{2} = -\frac{\pi}{2} $$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\pi\sqrt{x+1}=\pi$, I suggest substituting
$$
t=\pi(1-\sqrt{x+1})
$$
so the numerator becomes $\sin(\pi-t)=\sin t$. Next
$$
x=\left(1-\frac{t}{\pi}\right)^2-1=\frac{t^2-2\pi t}{\pi^2}
$$
so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\pi^2}{t-2\pi}\frac{\sin t}{t}
$$

On the other hand, the given limit is the derivative at $0$ of the function $f(x)=\sin(\pi\sqrt{x+1})$ and the chain rule gives
$$
f'(x)=\cos(\pi\sqrt{x+1})\cdot\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
so
$$
f'(0)=\cos\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi \cdot \sqrt{x+1})}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi-\pi \cdot \sqrt{x+1})}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}}{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}\frac{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}}{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\pi(1- \sqrt{x+1}))}{x}.\frac{(1+ \sqrt{x+1})}{(1+\sqrt{x+1})}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\pi(1- x-1)}{x(1+\sqrt{x+1})}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\pi(- x)}{x(1+\sqrt{x+1})}=-\frac\pi2$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt{x+1}=y+1\implies x=y^2+2y$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{(\pi \cdot \sqrt{x+1})}}{x}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin\pi(y+1)}{\pi y}\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac\pi{y+2}$$

$$=-\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin\pi y}{\pi y}\cdot\dfrac\pi{0+2}=?$$ as $\sin(\pi+A)=-\sin A$