# $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|-E(x)}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

On pose la fonction
$$f(x)=\sqrt{|x|-E(x)}$$
Est-ce que $f$ admet une limite en $p$ avec $p \in Z^*$?

Does $f$ admit a limit in $p$?

J'ai essayé d'encadrer l'expression et de diviser en deux cas $p > 0$ et $p < 0$ 
avec $E(x)$ est la partie entiere de $x$.

---

Let $f$ be defined as
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{\lvert x\rvert - \lfloor x\rfloor}.
$$
Fix $p\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. Does $f$ have a limit at $p$?

I tried to upper and lower bound the function, dividing into the cases $p>0$ and $p<0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "admet une limite en $p$"?

Comment: Admit a limit in $p$

Comment: If you find it difficult to write in english, we do ask of you to at least try. You may leave the french bits and just repeat the whole post in english to the best of your abilities. [Discussion on Meta.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19292/145141)

Comment: But what does it mean? $\lim_{x\to p} f(x)$? (You can explain in French if it's easier)

Comment: Does$f$ have a limit in $p$

Comment: Can you give an example of a "limit in p"?

Comment: Maybe it means a limit in probability.  Convergence in probability is a standard concept.

Comment: @user315918 Do you mean "Est-ce que $f$ admet une limite **au point $p$**"?

Comment: This is what he meant I think @ClementC.

Comment: @user315918 I edited your question to add an English version -- can you check?

Comment: Yes it is what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Take $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p\neq 0$.

- **Case $p>0$.** For any $h \in (0,1)$, $p+h>0$, $p-h > 0$, $\lfloor p+h\rfloor = p$ and $\lfloor p-h\rfloor=p-1$, so that $$f(p+h) = \sqrt{\lvert p+h\rvert - \lfloor p+h\rfloor} = \sqrt{p+h - p} = \sqrt{h}\xrightarrow[h\to0^+]{} 0$$
  but
  $$f(p-h) = \sqrt{\lvert p-h\rvert - \lfloor p-h\rfloor} = \sqrt{p-h - (p-1)} = \sqrt{1-h}\xrightarrow[h\to0^+]{} 1$$
  so $f$ is not continuous at $p$: both $\lim_{p^+} f$ and $\lim_{p^-} f$ exist,  but $\lim_{p^+} f\neq \lim_{p^-} f.$
- **Case $p<0$.** For any $h \in (0,1)$, $p+h<0$, $p-h < 0$, $\lfloor p+h\rfloor = p$ and $\lfloor p-h\rfloor=p-1$, so that $$f(p+h) = \sqrt{\lvert p+h\rvert - \lfloor p+h\rfloor} = \sqrt{-p-h - p} = \sqrt{-2p-h}\xrightarrow[h\to0^+]{} \sqrt{-2p}$$
  but
  $$f(p-h) = \sqrt{\lvert p-h\rvert - \lfloor p-h\rfloor} = \sqrt{-p+h - (p-1)} \xrightarrow[h\to0^+]{} \sqrt{-2p+1}$$
  so $f$ is not continuous at $p$.

---

Note that you can visualize the discontinuities by [looking at the graph of the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=Plot%5B+Sqrt(%7Cx%7C-Floor%5Bx%5D),+%7Bx,-3,3%7D%5D).