# $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\tan x \cdot \sqrt {\tan x}-\sin x \cdot \sqrt{\sin x}}{x^3 \sqrt{x}}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Calculate:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\tan x \cdot \sqrt {\tan x}-\sin x \cdot \sqrt{\sin x}}{x^3 \sqrt{x}}$$

I don't know how to use L'Hôpital's Rule.

I tried to make $\tan x =\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ for the term ${\sqrt{\tan x}}$.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html).

Comment: It's Forbidden to use it

Comment: Are you permitted to use Taylor Series ?

Answer (score 5):

You can first remove a few factors
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\tan x \cdot \sqrt {\tan x}-\sin x \cdot \sqrt{\sin x}}{x^3 \sqrt{x}}\\
=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\tan x \cdot \sqrt{\tan x}}{x \sqrt{x}}\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos x\sqrt{\cos x}}{x^2}\\
=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos x\sqrt{\cos x}}{x^2}.$$
Then multiply by the conjugate 
$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x^2(1+\cos x\sqrt{\cos x})},$$
evaluate the finite factor at denominator
$$=\frac12\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1-\cos x(1-\sin^2 x)}{x^2},$$
use trigonometric identitites
$$=\frac12\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{2\sin^2\frac x2+\cos x\sin^2 x}{x^2},$$
and conclude
$$=\left(\frac12\right)^2+\frac12.$$

---

We used

$$\frac{\tan x}x=\frac{\sin x}x\frac1{\cos x}\to 1,$$
$$\frac{\sin ax}x=a\frac{\sin ax}{ax}\to a.$$

Comment: $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos^3x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}(1+\cos x+\cos^2x)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos^2x}{x^2}\frac{1+\cos x+\cos^2x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{3}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\tan x \cdot \sqrt {\tan x}-\sin x \cdot \sqrt{\sin x}}{x^3 \sqrt{x}}
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\tan^{3/2}x-\sin^{3/2} x}{x^3 \sqrt{x}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin^{3/2}x}{x^{3/2}}\frac{\sec^{3/2}x-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{3/2}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sec^{3/2}x-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sec^{3/2}x-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\left(1+\frac12x^2+\frac5{24}x^4+\cdots\right)^{3/2}-1}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\left(1+\frac34x^2+\cdots\right)-1}{x^2}\\
&=\frac34
\end{align}$$

Comment: What's $sec$ means ?

Comment: @user315918 $\,\sec x\;$ = secant of $\;x=\frac1{\cos x}\;$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\tan x\sqrt{\tan x}-\sin x\sqrt{\sin x}}{x^3\sqrt x}=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\cdot\frac{\frac1{\cos^{3/2}x}-1}{x^2}=$$

$$=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\frac{1-\cos^{3/2}x}{x^2\cos^{3/2}x}=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\frac{1-\cos^2x+\cos^{3/2}x(\cos^{1/2}x-1)}{x^2\cos^{3/2}x}=$$

$$=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\left[\frac1{\cos^{3/2}x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2+\frac{\cos^{1/2}x-1}{x^2}\right]=$$

$$=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\left[\frac1{\cos^{3/2}x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2+\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2(\cos^{1/2}x+1)}\right]=$$

$$=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\left[\frac1{\cos^{3/2}x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2-\frac2{\cos^{1/2}x+1}\frac{\sin^2\frac x2}{x^2}\right]=$$

$$=\left(\frac{\sin x} x\right)^{3/2}\left[\frac1{\cos^{3/2}x}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2-\frac2{\cos^{1/2}x+1}\cdot\frac14\cdot\left(\frac{\sin\frac x2}{\frac x2}\right)^2\right]\xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{}$$

$$\rightarrow1\left[1\cdot1-\frac22\cdot\frac14\cdot1\right]=1-\frac14=\frac34$$