# If $p\mid4n!-1$ then $p>n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and define $a_{n}=4(1\cdot 2\cdot3 \cdots n)-1.$ Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p\mid a_{n}.$ Prove that $$p>n.$$

Comment: HInt:  $p≤n\implies p\;|\;n!$

Answer (score 1):

If $p\leq n$ then $p | n!$ since $n!=1 \cdot 2 \cdot... \cdot p \cdot... \cdot n$ Then you will have $p|4n!-1$ and $p|n!$. which means $p|1$. That cannot be true.

Comment: I think you may have taken a wrong turn at Albuquerque.

Comment: @BobHapp I'm sorry but I dont understand what that means...

Comment: As I reread your answer, I think now it's a matter of clarity, that your answer could be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a prime number $p \geq 2$, if $p \leq n$, then $p \mid n!$ as well as $4n!$ but not $4n! - 1$. Therefore we need $p > n$ such that $p \nmid n!$ nor $4n!$ in order to allow the possibility that $p \mid 4n! - 1$.

To give a concrete example: consider $n = 4$ and $p = 5$ or $19$. Then we have $4n! - 1 = 95 = 5 \times 19$. The primes less than $4$ are $2$ and $3$, but obviously $96$ is quite divisible by both of those.