# Prove that: $2^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod {9} \implies 2^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod {7}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that:
$$2^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod {9} \implies 2^{n} \equiv 1 \pmod {7}$$
Please a hint and a help

Comment: No we did not study it

Comment: Note that $7.9 = 2^6 - 1$.

Comment: @anomaly That's a weird way of writing multiplication, looks more like a decimal marker to me.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl: It's very common in number theory.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Use Fermat–Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $2^3\equiv-1\pmod9\implies$ord$_92=6\implies6\mid n$

If $n=6m,$  $$2^{6m}-1$$ is divisible by $$2^6-1$$  which is always divisible by $7$

Answer (score 1):

Raise 2 to successive powers and check against $2^n \equiv 1$ (mod 9). You will find the least such $n$ is ...  (fill in with your answer). Then show that if $2^n \equiv 1$ (mod 9) then $n$ must be divisible by that "least such $n$." Finally, show that this implies $2^n\equiv 1$ (mod 7) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put $n=6k+a, a \in \{0,1,..,5\}$. In this case,
$$2^n=2^{6k+a}=64^k.2^a \equiv 2^a \equiv 1 (\text{mod 9})$$
Imply that $a=0$. Then:
$$2^n=2^{6k}=64^k \equiv 1 (\text{mod 7}).$$